# Why should we not store the passwords or keys for encryption in source code for an iPhone App?

Tags: ios, security

Why should we not store the passwords or keys for encryption in source code for an iPhone App?

Is there any possibility for people to reverse engineer code and find the stored keys? or if the hard code values are stored in a location which is easily accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store keys in source code, yes they can be reverse engineered. You can make this even harder by making the key "generated" through a generator function but this is still an extra level of obfuscation. A really motivated attacker can get through that. Another drawback of this approach is that the same key will work on all instances of your application, unless the generator function generates a key deriving from some hardware constants.

Again, you have to do an analysis of how secure you want your application to be and how much effort you want to put into security. Security is always a trade off. It is not worthwhile to spend a lot of effort on security, when the probability or cost of an attack are extremely unlikely.

A more secure approach would be to create a random key and then store it in a secure storage on the device. I am not terribly familiar with the iOS Api and if such functionality is offered. On Windows there is something called [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) that provides this, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that gets into users' hands is accessible. Obfuscation of keys does part of the work, but doesn't eliminate the problem completely.